# Add new field to existing entity with JHipster

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I've a problem when I try to add a new field to an existing entity.
I run this command
yo jhipster:entity Libro and I choose [BETA] Yes, add more fields and relationships, but when I try to compile my project with ./mvnw I receive this error http://pastebin.com/SW1kpeDT

I also try to follow the guideline in jhipster site but I have the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal (at least in beta) because the update operation changed the Liquibase migration file `20161022122700_added_entity_Libro.xml` that created the entity, so Liquibase compares the checksum of the updated file with the checksum that was recorded in your database when migration was first run before update.

So you have these alternatives:

- create a new migration file to add only the new column (see [addColumn documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_column.html)), revert the creation migration to its original content using git, run your app to apply changes to your database. This is what you would do when your app is in production.
- clear the checksums by hand in `databasechangelog` table of your database(s)
- run `mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums` command against your database(s). Make sure your `pom.xml` includes correct configuration for maven-liquibase-plugin to access your db.
- use H2 in memory as dev database

As this feature is beta, this issue is probably going to be addressed.

**EDIT 2022:** since JHipster 7.0, there is the `--incremental-changelog` option that solves this.

Comment: If I try to use liquibase clearCheckSums I run in this error http://pastebin.com/ZhhXfveS. I also try your first advice but I have the same error. I don't know why but I'm not able to add new field to existing entity. WAIT: What are the correct step to follow your first advice. I make a new migration file and I copy all the contents of the original migration file in second and I add the new field, and after?

Comment: I've problem with first step. There are a tutorial step by step?. This point "revert the creation migration to its original content using git" is not clear for me

Comment: `git reset --hard config/liquibase/changelog/20161022122700_added_entity_Libro.xml`may work, check changes applied to the chnagelog folder

Comment: I get this in in memory H2 and the dev database aswell?

Comment: This do not seem to work now  jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL cant see the app tables

Comment: What about mvn compile liquibase:diff should work automatically?

Comment: You're going in all directions and mixing different questions into comments, please open your own questions with enough details and focus.