# JHipster modify the entity and update in DB

Tags: jhipster

How to update the DB(MySQL) after making changes in JHipster entity

Tried with mvnw liquibase:diff

Comment: please add some example code and error log(if you have any), so that others can understand your situation

Comment: ERROR 160 --- [-app-Executor-1] c.r.a.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:1 change sets check sum config/liquibase/changelog/20161128114009_added_entity_Registration.xml::20161128114009-1::jhipster is now: 
liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
config/liquibase/changelog/20161128114009_added_entity_Registration.xml::20161128114009-1::jhipster is now: 7:92917c8c7161699fb7ff9348051323c3
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328840/add-new-field-to-existing-entity-with-jhipster/40329781#40329781

Answer (score 2):

If you have made manual changes to your entity, you must create a Liquibase migration, add it to master.xml ancd then re-start your app. If you made changes to database, you must also update entity code.

Comment: I just added a new column from yo jhipster:entity registration and trying to update the table.. any particular command

Comment: You just have to restart your JHipster app

Answer (score 0):

mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums with this command I am able to resolve my issue. It worked