# Edit entity when have a database in production

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I have create my app with jhipster in july, and i have put it in production.

Now i need edit a entity.
When i use `jhipster entity` the subgenerator update the initial xml generate for the entity, but not is thes the correct work, the code need create a new xml with the update like: mvn liquibase:diff

Searching on the web i have foud this answere: [Add new field to existing entity with JHipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328840/add-new-field-to-existing-entity-with-jhipster). At a certain point the user say:

> create a new migration file to add only the new column (see addColumn
>   documentation), revert the creation migration to its original content
>   using git, run your app to apply changes to your database. ***This is
>   what you would do when your app is in production.***

In reference the last phrase, is the true? Jhipster entity subgenerator not support update of db but only initial creation?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

Either you write a manual Liquibase migration or you use liquibase:diff to help you in this process.

See official docs: https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates-with-the-maven-liquibasediff-goal

Comment: It's not an easy task, someone has already tried in the past and did not complete.